# My function starts 1, 1, 2, 4, 8 times and so on

Tags: javascript, html, function

I want to make quiz using objects. On the first page you can choose the difficulty level. Then my js file takes all of questions from array, and also shuffles the answers. After clicking on one of the answers another js file removes first item from array and displays next one. It happens first time, second, but when it comes to third this function "starts" two times in the row, next 4 times and so on. I don't know what is a problem.
Hope you all understand what I mean, I'm not very good at writing in English.

```js
const gothicTheme = {
  themeName: "Gothic",
  questionsEasy: [{
      id: 1,
      question: "dsaasd",
      answers: [{
          text: "sda",
          correct: true
        },
        {
          text: "Disdago",
          correct: false
        },
        {
          text: "Y'asdedsarion",
          correct: false
        },
        {
          text: "Wsa",
          correct: false
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      question: "Która osoba z podanych NIE jest przyjacielem Bezimiennego?",
      answers: [{
          text: "Cipher",
          correct: true
        },
        {
          text: "Lee",
          correct: false
        },
        {
          text: "Milten",
          correct: false
        },
        {
          text: "Diego",
          correct: false
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      question: "Kto jest dowódcą paladynów w Górniczej Dolinie, a kto w Khorinis?",
      answers: [{
          text: "Khorinis - Lord Hagen, GD - Garond",
          correct: true
        },
        {
          text: "Khorinis - Lord Garond, GD - Hagen",
          correct: false
        },
        {
          text: "Khorinis - Lord Rhobar, GD - Orik",
          correct: false
        },
        {
          text: "Khorinis - Lord Orik, GD - Rhobar",
          correct: false
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      question: "Które z podanych krain możemy odwiedzić podczas gameplayu Gothica 3",
      answers: [{
          text: "Myrtana, Nordmar, Varant",
          correct: true
        },
        {
          text: "Myrtana, Północne Ziemie, Varant",
          correct: false
        },
        {
          text: "Normard, Varant, Północne Ziemie",
          correct: false
        },
        {
          text: "Wyspy Południowe, Północne Ziemie, Niezbadane Krainy",
          correct: false,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      question: "Do oficjalnego kanonu zaliczamy, które części Gothica?",
      answers: [{
          text: "Gothic, Gothic 2, Gothic 2: Noc Kruka, Gothic 3",
          correct: true,
        },
        {
          text: "Gothic, Gothic 2: Noc Kruka, Gothic 3",
          correct: false,
        },
        {
          text: "Gothic, Gothic 2, Gothic 3",
          correct: false,
        },
        {
          text: "Gothic, Gothic: Mroczne Tajemnice, Gothic 2, Gothic 2: Noc Kruka, Gothic 3, Gothic 3: Zmierzch Bogów",
          correct: false,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      question: "Kto jest głównym antagonistą w dwóch pierwszych częściach gry",
      answers: [{
          text: "Śniący i Smok Ożywieniec",
          correct: true
        },
        {
          text: "Śniący i Bestia ",
          correct: false
        },
        {
          text: "Rhobar",
          correct: false
        },
        {
          text: "Wrzód",
          correct: false
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      question: "Kto spuszcza łomot Bezimiennemu po zesłaniu do kolonii?",
      answers: [{
          text: "Bullit",
          correct: true
        },
        {
          text: "Diego",
          correct: false
        },
        {
          text: "Rhobar",
          correct: false
        },
        {
          text: "Wrzód",
          correct: false
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      question: "Kto spuszcza łomot Bezimiennemu po zesłaniu do kolonii?",
      answers: [{
          text: "Bullit",
          correct: true
        },
        {
          text: "Diego",
          correct: false
        },
        {
          text: "Rhobar",
          correct: false
        },
        {
          text: "Wrzód",
          correct: false
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 9,
      question: "Kto spuszcza łomot Bezimiennemu po zesłaniu do kolonii?",
      answers: [{
          text: "Bullit",
          correct: true
        },
        {
          text: "Diego",
          correct: false
        },
        {
          text: "Rhobar",
          correct: false
        },
        {
          text: "Wrzód",
          correct: false
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      id: 10,
      question: "Kto spuszcza łomot Bezimiennemu po zesłaniu do kolonii?",
      answers: [{
          text: "Bullit",
          correct: true
        },
        {
          text: "Diego",
          correct: false
        },
        {
          text: "Rhobar",
          correct: false
        },
        {
          text: "Wrzód",
          correct: false
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};
const difficulties = document.querySelectorAll(".easy, .medium, .hard");

const easy = document.querySelector(".easy").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector("main").classList.toggle("nvisible");
  document.querySelector(".qAndA").classList.toggle("nvisible");
  test();
});
let questNumber = 1;
let number = 1;


const questionsIDs = gothicTheme.questionsEasy.map((e) => e.id);

const randomQuestionsIDs = questionsIDs.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

const randomAnswers = gothicTheme.questionsEasy.forEach((e) => {
  const randomOrder = e.answers.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
  return randomOrder;
});
const test = () => {


  const currentQuestID = randomQuestionsIDs.find((e) => {
    return e === randomQuestionsIDs[0];
  });
  const currentQuest = gothicTheme.questionsEasy.find(
    (e) => e.id === currentQuestID
  );


  document.querySelector("h3.questionValue").textContent =
    currentQuest.question;
  document.querySelector(".questionNumber").textContent = questNumber;

  document.querySelectorAll(".answer").forEach((e) => {

    if (e.classList.contains("answer1")) {
      e.textContent = currentQuest.answers[0].text;
    } else if (e.classList.contains("answer2")) {
      e.textContent = currentQuest.answers[1].text;
    } else if (e.classList.contains("answer3")) {
      e.textContent = currentQuest.answers[2].text;
    } else {
      e.textContent = currentQuest.answers[3].text;
    }
  });
  pickAnswer(randomQuestionsIDs);
  questNumber++;
};
const answers = document.querySelectorAll(".answer");

const pickAnswer = () => {

  for (let i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
    const ele = answers[i];
    ele.addEventListener("click", () => {
      randomQuestionsIDs.shift();
      test();
    });
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  color: white
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.min.css" />
  </head>

  <body class="gothicQuiz" style="background-color: rgb(76,55,55); position: relative">
    <main>
      <div class="choose-difficulty">
        <span>Wybierz poziom trudności:</span>
        <div class="easy">Easy</div>
      </div>
    </main>
    <div class="qAndA nvisible">
      <div class="question">
        <h2>Pytanie <span class="questionNumber"></span>:</h2>
        <h3 class="questionValue"></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="answers">
        <div class="answer answer1"><button class="answerBtn"></button></div>
        <div class="answer answer2"><button class="answerBtn"></button></div>
        <div class="answer answer3"><button class="answerBtn"></button></div>
        <div class="answer answer4"><button class="answerBtn"></button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ending"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: just a thought, did you try removing you event Lister `removeEventListener('click;, ele);` it might be because your listeners are triggered for each question.

Comment: That happens because `test` calls `pickAnswer` which attaches event handlers, and then in those handlers you call `test` again, which means it will call `pickAnswer` again and attach the same handlers another time. So you get increasingly more handlers that will respond to the `click` event, each time you click on an `answer`. Just call the `pickAnswer` outside of `test`.